# Erro no carregamento de modelo Spacy

Tags: python

Estou tentando carregar um modelo NER já treinado, que estava carregando normal até hoje, mas estou  recebendo o seguinte erro, seja importando o modelo treinado, seja importando pt_core_news_lg:

`nlp4 = spacy.load('/content/gdrive/My Drive/spacy_NER4')`

***ValueError: Cannot create vectors table with dimension 0.
If you're using pre-trained vectors, are the vectors loaded?***

Estou no Google Colab, seguindo as instalações:

`!pip install spacy==2.3.4`

`!python -m spacy download pt_core_news_lg`

Quando importo o meu modelo, gera esse erro. Alguém teria uma dica ou solução para esse problema?

Se eu instalar o *spacy-nightly*, gera outro erro:

**OSError: [E053] Could not read config.cfg from /content/gdrive/My Drive/spacy_NER4/config.cfg**

Entretanto, ao carregar o pt_core_news_lg, ele carrega normal

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução:
Primeiro encerrei a sessão do Google Colab e instalei de novo o spacy da versão 2.3.4, reiniciando-o.

É preciso carregar primeiro o modelo que tem os vetores dos quais o modelo NER foi treinado. No meu caso, treinei com pt_core_news_lg. Ao carregar esse modelo, os vetores pré-treinados serão carregados no ambiente e assim, servirão para o modelo NER citado `nlp4 = spacy.load('/content/gdrive/My Drive/spacy_NER4')`. Dessa forma, seguindo os códigos abaixo, consegui resolver o problema. É importante destacar que se você treinou um NER em uma versão específica do spacy, é importante todas as vezes carrega-la. Nas versões mais novas, como em `spacy-nightly` citado, já possui características e arquivos diferentes, ou seja, não vai ser compatível treinar e carregar modelos em diferentes versões do spacy.

Solução que encontrei:

`import spacy`

`spacy.load('pt_core_news_lg')`

`nlp4 = spacy.load('/content/gdrive/My Drive/spacy_NER4')`

Carregamento concluído

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Resolvi o problema mudando de conta, fazendo o backup dos modelos para outra conta no colab. Por enquanto, essa foi a maneira que achei para resolver isso

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).